# Error: method in class cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java

I'm getting this error message for my getYear, getMake, and getModel methods within my class car, because apparently they aren't being passed arguments. It appears to me that they are being passed arguments, but I'm still in a beginner in Java, so I'm not sure where I messed up.

```
public class NextCar {
public static final void main(String args[]) {

//Creates objects from Car class
Car c = new Car ();
Car c1 = new Car ();
Car c2 = new Car ();
Car c3 = new Car ();

//First object
//Prints mileage
c.start();
c.moveForward(6);
c.moveBackward(2);
c.moveForward(4);
System.out.println ("The car went " + c.mileage() + " miles.");

//Second object
//Prints year of car
c1.getYear(2050);
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c1.getYear());

//Third object
//Prints year and make of car
c2.getYear(2055);
c2.getMake("Google");
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c2.getYear() + " and the make is " + c2.getMake());

//Fourth object
//Prints year, make, and model of car
c3.getYear(2060);
c3.getMake("Google");
c3.getModel("Smart");
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c3.getYear() + " and the make is " +    
c3.getMake() + " and the model is " + c3.getModel());

}
}

//creates Car class
class Car {
public int year = 0;
public String make = "";
public String model = "";
public int miles = 0;
public boolean power = false;

public void start() {
    power = true;
}

public void moveForward(int mf) {
    if (power == true) {
        miles += mf;
    }
}

public void moveBackward(int mb) {
    if (power == true) {
        miles -= mb;
    }
}

public int mileage() {
    return miles;
}

public int getYear(int y) {
    year = y;
    return year;
}

public String getMake(String ma) {
    make = ma;
    return make;
}

public String getModel(String mo) {
    model = mo;
    return mo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Car` class `getYear` method takes an integer input:

```
public int getYear(int y)
```

but you call it few times without providing an input

```
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c1.getYear());

System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c2.getYear() + " and the make is " + c2.getMake());


System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c3.getYear() + " and the make is " +
```

thats the reason for your errors.

You probably want two methods `getYear`(to get the year value) and `setYear` (to set the year value) but you have defined only one. Probably this is what you need:

```
public void setYear(int y) {
    year = y;
}


public int getYear() {
   return year;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore look here:

```
c1.getYear(2050);
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + c1.getYear());
```

the getYear return a value. so you could do

```
int year = c1.getYear(2050);
System.out.println("The year of the car is " + year);
```

Similar for the others. Or as Juned said, use appropiate getters/setters